# Connect two PC with their IP address to send message (not in an internal network)

Tags: c#, winforms, network-programming

I think this is simple question but i did not find anything when i googled it.

How Can I connect two system to each other with their Ip address?
for internal network ip address i can use socket programming.but what if their ip addresses are not in an internal network?

Comment: Can you ping each machine from the other over the network?

Comment: dont know,for example my friend give his ip address to me and i want to connect to him to send some message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Socket programming is how you communicate using IP. It does not matter whether they are on the same "internal" network or not. If you can communicate via IP, then IP doesn't know about "internal".